# Split string in Java at certain characters, return the amount of times a message needs to be split

Tags: java, arrays

I haven't coded in Java for a long time and during the lockdown working on getting back into it. I have this puzzle I've come across and wondering if someone can help me with it:

1). Split the given string into the size of the given int

2). return how many times the string would need to be split for the given int

3). no splitting words

```
String random = "I want to take this and only send it at a certain number";

int random_number =12;

public int splitTheString (String random, int random_number) { 
    int total = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    String [] str = random.split(" ");

    for(int i=0; i<str.length;i++)
    {
        total += str[i].length();
        if(total < random_number){
            System.out.println(str[i] + " less than 12");
                    counter ++;
        } else { 
            System.out.println(str[i] + " More than 12");
                                counter ++;
        }

        System.out.println(total + " " +  counter);

        return counter;
```

}
}

So from main the method would be called: splitTheString (random, random_number)

I'm trying something like the above but think Im headed in the wrong direction. Can someone help out. Thanks

Edit:

Expected input:
Strings:

1). "Messages won't be too long"

2). "These messages are great"

3). "Random messages are fun to play with"

4). "Some won't be words like kkkk lllll pppp llll"

5). "All these will be the kinds of inputs"

Expected outputs, can be split:

1). "Messages", "won't be too", "long" => 3

2). "These", "messages are", "great" => 3

3). "Random", "messages are", "fun to play", "with" => 4

4). "Some won't be", "words like", "kkkk lllll", "pppp llll" => 4

5). "All these will", "be the kinds of", "inputs" =>

Comment: Could you show an example for "Split the given string into the size of the given int"? Or rather, some examples in general? *input -> expected output*

Comment: @akuzminykh added some above, the expected output would give me back the amount of times a message should be split. thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get the function. Your examples don't show the function as it is. Your function has two parameters. Unfortunately, your code is not valid Java as well. You have a `return` keyword in the signature. Your function returns `void` so there cannot be an output. The name of your function is `String` which is reserved by the `String` class.

Comment: @akuzminykh Yes you're right I copied it here incorrectly. The return would be showing the amount of output strings

Comment: @akuzminykh ammended it sorry about that, guess its due to tiredness.

Comment: Sam, can expected outputs 1 be like messages wont, be too, long or messages, wont, be too long? We have to split the sentences to 3 parts, and it does not matter how many words include that parts, does it?

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK so for output 1 it doesn't matter needs to be 3 parts, thanks

Comment: like @akuzminykh, I did not get the requirement either.  Can you please mention again like given inputs a sentence and an integer, expected results can be bla bla bla

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK sorry it's not clear, given inputs would be a sentence, given the integer say 12 we can only fit that many characters into a given message, how many times does the message need to be split. So for "Messages won't be too long", would need to be split 3 times,  "Messages", "won't be too", "long". Return would be an int 3. I guess we need to look at the next elements to decide?

Comment: Now it is clear for me, thanks Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, DEBUG your code, follow the changes of the variables value on every iteration, I am sure you can see where the things start going wrong.

Beloved is just an example, start with

```
static int splitter(String fullSentence, int maxChar) {
```

do string-split as you did, define two variables, one for count like yours, other for the current split word(s),

```
String split = "";
int count = 0;
```

iterate the words of full sentence,

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
```

check if split + words[i] 's length is less than the maxChar, do not forget to add 1 for blank between the words,

```
    // check if words[i] is blank or empty!!!
    if (split.concat(words[i]).length() + 1 <= maxChar) {
        split = split.length() == 0 ? words[i] : split.concat(" " + words[i]);
    }
    else {
        // we reached max possible chars
        if (split.length() > 0) {
            System.out.print(split + ", ");
            count++;
        }
        split = words[i];
    }
```

when you finished the iteration, check again if split words has some value, even  check if it includes last word of full sentence then report it and increase the count if necessary

```
System.out.println(" => " + count);
```

end return the count;

```
return count;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, sorry yes I pasted the wrong code then tried amending it on here :-| was quite tired last night and left it. This code is great but problem is output from say "Messages, won't be too, long" is Messages, won't be too,  => 2. Seems to cut off the last word 'long', I've tested a few strings and the last word seems to cut off

Comment: Greats, then just add the `System.out.print(split + ", "); count++;` lines again before the `System.out.println(" => " + count);`.  And get some rest, virus lockdown is not helping everyone.